# Why is this list index out of range in Leetcode?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve the Longest Common Prefix problem in Python3 (https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/) in LeetCode but when I submit I get the following:
"
IndexError: list index out of range
secondWord = list(strs[1]) "
My code is provided below, and when I run it through the example test cases it works. I understand that there is a simpler solution with zip, but could someone please explain to me why the list index is out of range?
The input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]

Code:

```
def longestCommonPrefix(self, strs: List[str]) -> str:
    firstWord = list(strs[0])
    secondWord = list(strs[1])
    thirdWord = list(strs[2])

    longestCommonPrefix = ""

    if firstWord[0] == secondWord[0]:
        for i,char in enumerate(firstWord):
            if char == secondWord[i] and char == thirdWord[i]:
                longestCommonPrefix += char
            else:
                break
    return longestCommonPrefix
```

Comment: Why do you convert a string to a list?

Comment: Try this input - `strs` as ["stool", "study", ""]    Also read the `constraints` again.